# using psuedoclasses :not and :before together

Tags: html, css

My goal here is to add content before every child element except for the first one. (This is so that I can space out the elements of an html form without making them be spaced too far from the top.) I know "\A" is what I can add before an element to make a new line via CSS. Every which way I try to combine the adding content :before and :not(:first-child), I get invalid CSS and it doesn't render any CSS.

I can't seem to be able to combine the two css psuedo-class selectors `:not` and `:before`.

## HTML:

```
<div id="demo1">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
</div>
<br>
<div id="demo2">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
</div>
```

## CSS:

```
#demo1 p:not(:first-child) {
    color: red;
}
#demo2 p:before {
    content: "A";
}
```

...

## [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x0s54kw2/)

On the JS fiddle I'm adding the actual `A` character before each line, it is easier to see that way. How can I combine these two CSS psuedo-class selectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve it like this:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L4h4m1uc/)**

```
#demo2 p:not(:first-child):before  {
    content: "A";
}
```

Comment: Oh, well I guess I hadn't tried that. It makes sense, more sense than `p:before:not(:first-child)` (which doesn't work) [i've got to wait 5mins to accept your answer]